# Azure Notification Hub compatible with Service Workers?

Tags: azure, push-notification, service-worker, azure-notificationhub

Can Azure Notification Hub work with Javascript browser ServiceWorkers (Notification and Push API)? Reading the documentation, it seems not to. However, I want to make sure.

Azure Notification Hub only seems to connect to a PNS and Not to service workers. (Apple Push Notification Service (APNS), Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), and Windows Notification Service (WNS))

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of time of writing, your understanding is correct. Here's our [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq#do-you-support-text-message-email-or-web-notifications) stating such. This being said, the Azure Notification Hubs team is aware of the ask and has backlogged support for browser push.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful, feel free to write hyphen -MSFT suffixed by your name, I noticed thats what lot of Microsoft staff do in stackoverflow, appreciate it

Comment: hi Andrew, one other quick question, is Azure Notification Hub setup for Government Clients,  or only Corporate public clients? There is a difference between Government and Corporate cloud I believe, thanks

Comment: @earlwaltonluv3462 yes, Azure Notification Hubs currently supports sovereign clouds (US, China, Germany). See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/ (under `Azure Government` tab).